# difficulty translating liferay

Tags: translation, liferay

When I modify the Language_pt_PT.properties and restart the server, nothing happens. The modifications I've done don't show up.

I've also tried changing other language file with no success.

What might be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of liferay do you use? Where is your Language_pt_PT.properties? Did you switch to that language in browser (from language portlet)?

Comment: version 6, Language_pt_PT.properties is inside portal-impl.jar and I've switched to that language by putting "/pt_PT/" in the url, after the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: I made a backup copy of portal-impl.jar to the same folder of the original. The server was loading the files in the backup and not the new files.

Lame and rookie.

Sorry guys and thank you for your effort.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and override languages by creating a plugin (e.g. a hook) instead of manually patching the installation. This is a lot better to port to the next version/update. And you can't run into this class of error.

Comment: https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portal+Hook+Plugins#section-Portal+Hook+Plugins-Language+Bundles

Answer (score 0):

I would copy the file to every locale that uses Portuguese just in case you've accidentally selected that locale instead. From memory, the only other country that I can think of that speaks Portuguese is Brazil - Language_pt_BR.properties.

Like Martin mentioned,

Also there are 2 settings for languages, 1 for the user and 1 for the server. If you happened to just change the servers language preferences, you'll still need to switch it for the logged in user because the users preference takes precedence and this option will be set at the time the user was created.

Comment: what do you mean by "classes" folder? I'm trying to change a production site.

Comment: You are right, I misread the location of the contents folder. How are you changing the Language_pt_PT.properties file?